# Is there a minimum system specification for installing snap?

Tags: linux, terminal, debian, sudo, snap

I tried installing snap on debian 10 buster using the sudo command. When I run the command "sudo snap install core" I get the error message:

*system does not fully support snapd: cannot mount squashes image using "squashfs": mount: /tmp/sanity-mountpoint-600122688: mount failed: operation not permitted*

What could be the cause? Thanks.

Comment: The error message says it all. You lack sanity if you _want to_ install this crap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be several reasons for this problem:

1. I had to add the repo `add deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free` into my `/etc/apt/sources.list` and then`apt update`. My original repositories list didn't contain the squashfuse package.
2. Try this:
   `sudo apt install libsquashfuse0 squashfuse fuse`
3. You may also need `sudo modprobe loop`

Answer (score 0):

Beside installing `apt install fuse` it is important to make sure that you are running snap on an operation system that allows for it.

For example trying to run snap inside a container (a VPS, or a docker container) that does not have the correct configuration to run snap, snap will be able to install once, but will not work after restart, and this kind of error messages will be present in the syslog:

```
Oct 28 22:21:20 myhost snapd[628]: daemon.go:247: started snapd/2.55.5+20.04 (series 16; classic; devmode) ubuntu/20.04 (amd64) linux/5.4.0-1160.21.1.vz7.174.1.
Oct 28 22:21:20 myhost snapd[628]: main.go:129: system does not fully support snapd: cannot mount squashfs image using "squashfs": mount: /tmp/sanity-mountpoint-151175218: mount failed: Operation not permitted.
Oct 28 22:21:20 myhost snapd[628]: daemon.go:340: adjusting startup timeout by 45s (pessimistic estimate of 30s plus 5s per snap)
```

More on that here:
https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/system-does-not-fully-support-snapd-cannot-mount-squashfs-image-using-squashfs/132689/13

also some keywords to look for on this topic and how to allow containers to run snap correctly would be:

```
--cap-add SYS_ADMIN
--device /dev/fuse
```

Answer (score -1):

Also make sure if you are on kali apt update sometimes does not work so do sudo apt update then it works after snap restart you computer btw

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35399240)